# Split text only by comma or (comma and space) not only with space

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want a regex expression that extract values seperated by commas.

Sample input: `"John Doe, Jack, , Henry,Harry,,Rob"`
Expected output:

```
John Doe
Jack
Henry
Harry
Rob
```

I tried `[\w ]+` but blank values and extra spaces are getting included

Comment: `[e for e in re.split(r'\s*,\s*', ur_str) if e]`

Comment: The question needs some code. What have you tried so far please ? also, what is the expect output that you are seeking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> s="John Doe, Jack, , Henry,Harry,,Rob"
```

You can do:

```
>>> [e for e in re.split(r'\s*,\s*',s) if e]
['John Doe', 'Jack', 'Henry', 'Harry', 'Rob']
```